# Operate a Touchscreen Device using Raspberry Pi GPIO Wire

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, touchscreen

So I saw this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ElZec033vQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClFSUXebY7Q
This video does it without the whole circuitry.

And I wanted to do something similar, but more controlled.
I want to be able to use a raspberry pi to operate a phone screen (like your finger does) and be able to code how long between turning the touch on and off. I'm using Python. I have a penny on my screen and the wire touching it. The wire is connected to GPIO 17. When I first boot up the pi, touching the wire to the penny does nothing. I have a program that registers GPIO 17 as an output and turns it on and off. When connected to an LED, it does just that. However, it constantly activates the phone without ever turning off, even when I stop the program. I tried cleanup(), which does work in a weird way. If I hold it to the penny, cleanup() doesn't do anything and the wire continues to activate the phone. But if cleanup() has already happened and I briefly break the connection, then it no longer activates the phone.

How can I code a wire to put out a signal and turn off said signal when I want?

The guy in the video is using C and an arduino, so basically I want to convert that to a Raspberry Pi with Python.

Answer (score 0):

use the Gpiozero library .... there look for Led

```
import  gpiozero
import time
coin=gpiozero.LED("GPIO17")

while(1):
   coin.on()
   time.sleep(1)
   coin.off()
```

this code should control GPIO17 but you can choose another. Just try

Comment: I tried basically the same thing as this, but my problem comes down to a couple things. First, with this it just constantly activates on. I'm not sure, as I don't know a lot about electronics, but I know the negative end of a battery will activate a phone screen, as well as the positive one. When it gets turned off, I don't think that it shuts the wire off completely.

Comment: Try to conect via USB the phone and the Rasp and then try to run the code.... that way the negatives are joined together

Comment: Alright, I tried connecting the phoen via USB and running the code that way, but it's still not turning off. (I did add a time.sleep(1) at the bottom to make sure it stays off for a full second before turning back on) Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add a resistor and then connect it to the touch like in this example of the LED: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html

Comment: What amount of resistor do you recommend using? I found anything over 10k stops all functionality, but anything less doesn't have an effect.